# How can i update my table on server when i add new records in Mysql query browser on my locall pc?

Tags: mysql, browser

I use Mysql query browser on my pc for data entry,appreciate that let me how can i update my table on server after enter new records in Mysql query browser? is there any way that we sync to table(on server and on client )and sending new records to server?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your local and remote MySQL databases in sync, the obvious solution would be to use the [replication features](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) built into MySQL.

Comment: Is it on Mysql query browser?

Comment: @Kaveh It's a feature of the MySQL RDBMS itself. If you read the link in my answer all will be revealed.

Comment: Is it possible to explain more?how can i use it?

Comment: @Kaveh Read the documentation - that's what it's there for. (It'll explain it better than I can.) :-)

Comment: Please tell me that replication is my solution? On my server(share host)i have a db(magazine)and on server i have access to phpmyadmin,on my pc i have the same db and when i want enter new records to tables i use "Mysql query browser" then in "Mysql A dmistrator" i make .sql file from a table and import to server via phpmyadmin ,this take lot of time,now i want this: suppose that i enter 30 new records to tbarticle ,i want then connect to my server and add these 30 new records to tbarticle is it possible ?and how?

Comment: @Kaveh If you set up replication, any changed made to the "master" server will automatically occur on the "slave". This might not be the ideal scenario by the sounds of things, but it's the only way to automate the process if you don't want to manually create update files, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot,on phpmyadmin there is synchronize tab ,synchronization can be another option?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you have 2 data stores - one local, and one remote. Your question doesn't explicitly state that you actually have 2 separate databases, only that you're using MySQL Query Browser. You mention the MySQL Query Browser is on your PC, but it's not clear which database(s) it's connecting to. Is it a local database? Remember: the MySQL Query Browser is just an application that connects to a MySQL database.

It sounds as if you're looking for replication between MySQL servers. You mention 'sending new records' to the 2nd server. Are you looking for delete & update operations to be synchronized as well? A bit more information/requirements are needed before deciding on a solution.

The [MySQL docs on Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) will get you started on replication, if that's the solution you need. This assumes your database hosts are in a master-slave relationship. That is, there is one good copy of data, and the other is to be a mirror for the master.

Comment: On my server(share host) i have a db(magazine) and on server i have access to phpmyadmin,on my pc i have the same db and when i want enter new records to tables i use "Mysql query browser" then in "Mysql A dmistrator" i make .sql file from a table and import to server via phpmyadmin ,this take lot of time,now i want this:

Comment: This: suppose that i enter 30 new records to tbarticle ,i want then connect to my server and add these 30 new records to tbarticle is it possible ?and how?